# RecyclerView images are not visible after setting arraylist from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, gson

In my app, I have two activities
**1. RecorderActivity
2. GridViewActivity**

In RecorderActivity there is an option in toolbar called **select image** when this option clicked GridViewActivity is opened.
In GridViewActivity I have two option in toolbar called capture image from the camera and select image from the gallery.

When images are selected from gallery it is displayed in recyclerView in GridViewActivity like this

[image]

After that, I saved this ArrayList to SharedPreferences.

This is the code

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        int count=0;
        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            if (data.getData() != null) {
                //if single image is selected
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePath, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                arrayList.add(new Images(imageUri.toString()));
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        // Get the cursor
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePath, null, null, null);
                        // Move to first row
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        arrayList.add(new Images(uri.toString()));
                        count++;
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            imagesAdapter=new ImagesAdapter(context,arrayList);
            sharedPref.save(arrayList); //store arraylist in SharedPref
            sharedPref.updateCount(count); //store images count in SharedPref
            Log.d("ROHIT","data saved");
            setRecyclerView();
        }
    }
```

After that when I pressed back and again when I clicked on select image option in RecorderActivity again GridviewActivity opened but now RecyclerView cards are just blank image is not dislaying in it.

[image]

This is the code where I getting ArrayList back from SharedPref in onCreate()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    autoFitGridLayoutManager=new AutoFitGridLayoutManager(context,250);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(autoFitGridLayoutManager);
    arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    sharedPref=new SharedPref(context);
    if (sharedPref.getCount()==0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No images...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String response=sharedPref.getImages();
        arrayList=gson.fromJson(response,new TypeToken<ArrayList<Images>>(){}.getType()); //gettign ArrayList back from SharedPref
        Log.d("ROHIT", String.valueOf(sharedPref.getCount()));
        Log.d("ROHIT", String.valueOf(arrayList.size())); //arraylist size is also correct after getting it from SharedPref
        imagesAdapter=new ImagesAdapter(context,arrayList);
        setRecyclerView();
    }
}
public void setRecyclerView() {
    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback=new ItemMoveCallback(imagesAdapter);
    ItemTouchHelper touchHelper=new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
}
```

After that when I again select the same image from Gallery it displays the previous image and the newly selected image in RecyclerView.

[image]

Please tell me what's the problem in my code
or tell me If there is any other way to achieve this that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is really simple

No need of using Gson!

Note: I'm giving you the logic to solve your problem however you need to modify it as per your code

Try this when saving images in shared preference

```
Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
textEncode.setText(encodedImage);

SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit=shre.edit();
edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
edit.commit();
```

Try this when retrieving images from shared preferences (Hint: Create a new arraylist and create a loop which will add images until it reaches last position):

```
eg :ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array_image.add(R.drawable.image6);
array_image.add(R.drawable.image1);

SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String previouslyEncodedImage = shre.getString("image_data", "");

if( !previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    imageConvertResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```